# IllegalArgumentException at javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField.setChars

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I have wrote a simple web service in .NET which return a string value.

```
[WebMethod]
    public string DeveloperInfo()
    {
        return "Chamara is the appliaction developer";
    }
```

I need to consume it using a J2ME application.following is the code i have used

```
if (displayable == ServiceForm) {
        if (command == exitCommand1) {
            // write pre-action user code here
            switchDisplayable(null, getTaskList());
            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (command == okCommand2) {
        try
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable()
          {
              public void run()
              {
         try {
                  service1.Service1_Stub service=new service1.Service1_Stub();

             String Info= service.DeveloperInfo().toString();
             txtService.setString(Info);
                // write post-action user code here
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
              }
          }).start();
        }catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e.toString());}
```

It gives the following Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField.setChars(TextField.java:747)
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField.setString(TextField.java:666)
    at com.sliit.j2me.tutorial.TaskList$1.run(TaskList.java:155)
```

Where I have got wrong?

Comment: can you make sure what Info String contains ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems TextBox constraint fails.
Ex. The Text is set to take input numbers and you try to set alphabets into it.
check it and if it isn't the case then post the contain of Info.

Comment: Thanks...textBox maximum size is 32.webservice return string have more than 32 characters..

Comment: One more thing,can u tell me what is the control that i can use to include more than 32 characters.

Comment: From your code it seems you are using NetBeans, So you can set the max. size for textField from UI. its not 32 only. you can set it.